# Venmo API - differing payment IDs

Tags: json, paypal, venmo

When I POST a payment using Venmo's API the response object has all the data from the payment including obviously an ID that's usually 20 characters long. This makes sense because Venmo handles a lot of payments.

But when I do a GET request to see my recent payments, and I see the payment I just made, the ID is different. It's only 8 characters.

When I do a GET for just a single payment using it's ID, the long ID doesn't work..but the short one does. This is all in JSON btw.

My goal is simple: to store the payment ID of the payment I just made to my DB so I can use it later to search for that payment on Venmo's API.

Anyone with some API experience or better, venmo API experience have any idea whats going on here?

The URLs:

```
https://sandbox-api.venmo.com/payments/" + verificationPaymentId + "?access_token=" + token;

https://api.venmo.com/v1/payments/" + payment_id + "?access_token=" + token;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens when you mix naked and `/v1` endpoints.

Can you confirm you are using http://api.venmo.com/v1 as your base URL for everything?

Comment: You're right. I wasn't. I was posting with the V1 and finding it in the sandbox api. So the ID would be different between the two? If so, why are 'new' posts being found?

Comment: forgot the /v1 ...I'm so embarrassed. Thank you